# How do I turn on specialization to eliminate runtime dictionary passing?

Tags: typeclass, purescript, specialization

While looking at poor runtime performance of some Purescript code I wrote, I noticed that the generated Javascript code contains dictionary passing for overloaded definitions for e.g. `transformers` monads. However, all my exported functions are monomorphic, so the compiler should have no trouble specializing these overloaded occurrences.

If this were Haskell compiled with GHC, I'd check optimization flags, and things like making sure nothing is marked `NOINLINE` and that unfoldings are properly exposed for specialisable definitions. What are the equivalent techniques for Purescript?

Answer (score 0):

[PureScript v0.15.3](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/releases/tag/v0.15.3) has an optimization for “common subexpression elimination for expressions created by the compiler in the process of creating and using
typeclass dictionaries.” Maybe that will speed up your code.

Comment: I can't really observe any effect of this. I have one module that is still compiled into a `.js` file where dictionaries are passed around, and the `.js` file resutling from my other, main module, still doesn't contain any specialised versions of these functions.

Comment: If you have a case where you think you should be seeing the optimization but you're not, then I'm sure the PureScript project would like you to open an issue and describe what you're seeing.